# Date column in int

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date column in dataframe . I am looking to get int value from this date column

for example : for below input value
2021-04-30 10:05:02
the output should be 20210430105022

If i use the below code for hour,minute and second

```
df['T_Hour'] = df_data['date_time'].dt.hour
df_data['T_Minute'] =df_data['date_time'].dt.minute
df_data['T_Second'] =df_data['date_time'].dt.second
```

It will give me hh:mm:ss as 10 5 2  which is missing the zero's.How do i include those zero to get the final out put has 20210430105022

Comment: You need `100502` from `10:05:02`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
d = {'date_time':pd.to_datetime(['2021-04-30 10:05:02','2021-04-30 10:50:02'])}
df_data = pd.DataFrame(d)

df_data['out'] = df_data['date_time'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S').astype(np.int64)
print (df_data)
            date_time             out
0 2021-04-30 10:05:02  20210430100502
1 2021-04-30 10:50:02  20210430105002
```